# Restart a process inside a Docker container whenever the config file changes

Tags: docker, containers, restart

I have a DockerFile that starts 2 processes in a single docker container using a jar file and a config file as an argument

java -jar process1.jar process1.cfg &
java -jar process2.jar process2.cfg

process1.cfg and process2.cfg are residing in mounted directories. Now whenever there is a change in any of the cfg files, I would need to restart the corresponding process for the new change to take effect. All these to be done programmatically using Java in a REST microservice that updates the config file and restarts the process. Any idea on how to go about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be generically solved by your Java app starting a config change monitoring service/thread, which manages the actual business service/thread(s) by starting it in the beginning and restarting on any change (if the change actually needs a restart). File change monitoring is standard Java functionality. The solution does not need any REST, it is not bound to microservice architecture (although it is more sensible within it) and it is not limited by or to docker containers.

If you do not want any file-based configs, do the same, but the monitoring bit can be e.g. a vert.x-based web server listening for external REST requests supplying configs, on start or for any update. The rest remains the same.

In my current workplace we actually have a module that functions in exactly this way, it is deployed to a docker and uses both file system monitoring and vert.x web server for config changes.

You can even go further and make the monitoring bit start multiple instances internally if multiple configs need to be supported.